# How to get an array of objects from a normal array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to find a way to get an array of objects from a normal array without using a for loop.

An example for that I want to turn that array:
`[1,2,3,4,5]`

To be an array of objects like that:
`[{x:1, y:2}, {x:2, y:4}, {x:3, y:6}, {x:4, y:8}, {x:5, y:10}]`
without using a for loop

Comment: What effort have you made? This seems to be a 'do my homework for me' question. Remember that SO is here to help you to *debug code that you have written*. It is not here to write code for you.

Comment: Kinda makes no sense as well, in the example you gave us you only have `[1,2,3,4,5]` but you want to "transform" that into an array of objects that have other elements that are not present in your initial array like `6`,`8`,`10` so what kind of rule are you even following to create your array?

Answer (score 4):

You could [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the array to a new array of objects:

```js
result = [1,2,3,4,5].map(i => ({x: i, y: i*2}));
```